# Why is this ColorAnimation Code not working?

Tags: xaml, animation, output, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am using this code to animate two gradient stops made with LinearGradientBrush. On execution, the code just stays at the initial gradient stops and there is no animation whatsoever. Neither is there any exception/error.

XAML:

```
   <StackPanel x:Name="myStackPanel" Loaded="myStackPanel_Loaded">
    <StackPanel.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard x:Name="colorStoryboard1" Completed="colorStoryboard1_Completed">
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="GradStop1" 
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty = "Color"
                          From="Lavender" To="PaleVioletRed" Duration="0:0:5"/>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="GradStop2" 
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty = "Color"
                          From="White" To="Lavender" Duration="0:0:5"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>

    </StackPanel.Triggers>

    <Panel.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop x:Name="GradStop1" Color="Lavender" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop x:Name="GradStop2" Color="White" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Panel.Background>

</StackPanel>
```

Trigger Code:

```
 public MainPage()
    {

        this.InitializeComponent();
        colorStoryboard1.Begin();

    }
```

Comment: How are you invoking the animation? Might also show your panel.

Comment: @ChrisW. Edited the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Triggers`, `EventTrigger`, `BeginStoryboard` are not commonly used in UWP app, these APIs mainly exist for compatibility in XAML originally used for Microsoft Silverlight. In UWP app we should use built-in animations.

But for your scenario, if your animation causes a layout change or otherwise has the potential to impact performance on the UI thread, you often need to explicitly enable the animation to see it run. It means, you need to enable the `EnableDependentAnimation` property. For more info, you can refer to [ColorAnimation.EnableDependentAnimation property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297577/why-is-this-coloranimation-code-not-working).

So you can modify your code for example like this:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="myStackPanel">
    <StackPanel.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard x:Name="colorStoryboard1" Completed="colorStoryboard1_Completed">
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="GradStop1"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty = "Color"
                        From="Lavender" To="PaleVioletRed" Duration="0:0:5" EnableDependentAnimation="True" />
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="GradStop2"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty = "Color"
                        From="White" To="Lavender" Duration="0:0:5" EnableDependentAnimation="True" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </StackPanel.Triggers>

    <StackPanel.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop x:Name="GradStop1" Color="Lavender" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop x:Name="GradStop2" Color="White" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </StackPanel.Background>
</StackPanel>
```

For this method, since you already defined the trigger in XAML, there is no need to trigger it again in the code behind.

And in case you're interest in the built-in animation in UWP, here is a sample:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="std">
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="GradStop1"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty = "Color"
                            From="Lavender" To="PaleVioletRed" Duration="0:0:5" EnableDependentAnimation="True" />
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="GradStop2"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty = "Color"
                            From="White" To="Lavender" Duration="0:0:5" EnableDependentAnimation="True" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel x:Name="myStackPanel" Loaded="myStackPanel_Loaded">    
        <StackPanel.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop x:Name="GradStop1" Color="Lavender" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop x:Name="GradStop2" Color="White" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </StackPanel.Background>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

code behind:

```
private void myStackPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    std.Begin();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This did the job perfectly.